# very bright white star before sunrise

Tags: amateur-observing, venus

I'm from the Philippines, this is the first time I've seen such a bright star. I don't normally see stars at all cause of my poor eyesight but this star is very bright and really noticeable.

I took the first picture around 4:45 am, then now the little white which is still the star. The second I took it around 5:15 am when the sun already rising. The star and the sun are both in my east. The star is like going up while the sun is rising. [image]
[image]

Answer (score 7):

An exceptionally bright star in the morning or evening is usually the planet Venus.

In May 2017, Venus is rising about two hours before the sun, and is by far the brightest star-like object in the morning sky. As it moves around the sun, it will get less bright. In a telescope, you would see it change from a crescent at the beginning of the month, to a semi-circle by the end. #

Planetarium software, such as Stellarium, can show the position of stars and planets at a given time and so help identify stars and planets.

Look out for Venus on the Morning of May 22, when it will be close to the crescent moon.

Answer (score 5):

Similarly to James K, I suspected that such an object may be Venus.

To confirm this, I loaded up Stellarium, and set the location to Victoria, Philippines. I took your time and date as well. A screenshot of the view seems to confirm that your object is in fact Venus.

[image: A view of Venus in the Eastern sky on the morning of May-14 2017, from Victoria, Philippines.]

I highly recommend downloading Stellarium for yourself. It is free, and allows you to check the night sky from any location on Earth at any time.

Comment: Thats cool!! i've seen venus!!